# Generate a list of dates between 2 dates for more than one record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write SQL to generate the following data

```
Date         Count
2018-09-24   2
2018-09-25   2
2018-09-26   2
2018-09-27   2
2018-09-28   2
2018-09-29   1
```

A sample of the base table I am using is

```
ID      StartDate   EndDate
187267  2018-09-24  2018-10-01
187270  2018-09-24  2018-09-30
```

So I'm trying to get a list of dates between 2 dates and then count how many base data records there are in each date.

I started using a temporary table and attempting to loop through the records to get the results but I'm not sure if this is the right approach.

I have this code so far

```
WITH ctedaterange 
     AS (SELECT [Dates] = (select ea.StartWork from EngagementAssignment ea where ea.EngagementAssignmentId IN(SELECT ea.EngagementAssignmentId
                                                                                                            FROM EngagementLevel el INNER JOIN
                                                                                                            EngagementAssignment ea ON el.EngagementLevelID = ea.EngagementLevelId
                                                                                                            WHERE el.JobID = 15072 and ea.AssetId IS NOT NULL))
         UNION ALL
         SELECT [dates] + 1 
         FROM   ctedaterange 
         WHERE  [dates] + 1 < = (select ea.EndWork from EngagementAssignment ea where ea.EngagementAssignmentId IN(SELECT ea.EngagementAssignmentId
                                                                                                            FROM EngagementLevel el INNER JOIN
                                                                                                            EngagementAssignment ea ON el.EngagementLevelID = ea.EngagementLevelId
                                                                                                            WHERE el.JobID = 15072 and ea.AssetId IS NOT NULL)))
SELECT [Dates], Count([Dates])
FROM   ctedaterange 
GROUP BY [Dates]
```

But I get this error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I get correct results when the job I use only generates one record in the subselect in the where clause, ie:

```
SELECT ea.EngagementAssignmentId
FROM EngagementLevel el INNER JOIN
EngagementAssignment ea ON el.EngagementLevelID = ea.EngagementLevelId
WHERE el.JobID = 15047 and ea.AssetId IS NOT NULL
```

generates one record.

The results look like this:

```
Dates                   (No column name)
2018-09-24 02:00:00.000 1
2018-09-25 02:00:00.000 1
2018-09-26 02:00:00.000 1
2018-09-27 02:00:00.000 1
2018-09-28 02:00:00.000 1
2018-09-29 02:00:00.000 1
2018-09-30 02:00:00.000 1
2018-10-01 02:00:00.000 1
```

Comment: how your count 2 in sample output for date 25

Comment: I would recommend looking at how I've got the start date and end date in my answer - You can get them both into variables before writing the cte so your code will be much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e76bfdcb785001f86252b8c0afa14ba0)

```
 WITH cte1
     AS (SELECT id,sdate,edate from t
     union all
     select c.id,DATEADD(DAY, 1, c.sdate),c.edate from cte1 c where DATEADD(DAY, 1, c.sdate)<=c.edate
        ) 
SELECT sdate,count(id) as total FROM   cte1 
group by sdate
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Output:

```
sdate      total
2018-09-24  2
2018-09-25  2
2018-09-26  2
2018-09-27  2
2018-09-28  2
2018-09-29  2
2018-09-30  1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can generate according to your range by changing from and to date

```
 DECLARE 
    @DateFrom DATETIME = GETDATE(),
    @DateTo DATETIME = '2018-10-30';

WITH DateGenerate 
AS (
    SELECT @DateFrom as MyDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, MyDate)
    FROM DateGenerate
    WHERE MyDate < @DateTo
   )

SELECT 
    MyDate
FROM 
    DateGenerate;
```

Comment: @TDav i just post about date generation but for count i need to generate based on your table column min and max

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you only have a low date range, you can use a recursive CTE as demonstrated in the other answers. The problem with a recursive CTE is with large ranges, where it starts to be ineffective - So I wanted to show you a different approach, that builds the calendar CTE without using recursion.

First, Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    ID int,
    StartDate date,
    EndDate date
)
INSERT INTO @T (ID, StartDate, EndDate) VALUES
(187267, '2018-09-24', '2018-10-01'),
(187270, '2018-09-24', '2018-09-30')
```

Then, get the first start date and the number of dates you need in the calendar cte:

```
DECLARE @DateDiff int, @StartDate Date

SELECT @DateDiff = DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(StartDate), Max(EndDate)),
       @StartDate = MIN(StartDate)
FROM @T
```

Now, construct the calendar cte based on `row_number` (that is, unless you already have a numbers (tally) table you can use):

```
;WITH Calendar(TheDate)
AS
(
    SELECT TOP(@DateDiff + 1) DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @@SPID)-1, @StartDate)
    FROM sys.objects t0
    -- unremark the next row if you don't get enough records...
    -- CROSS JOIN sys.objects t1 
)
```

Note that I'm using `row_number() - 1` and therefor have to select `top(@DateDiff + 1)`

Finally - the query:

```
SELECT TheDate, COUNT(ID) As NumberOfRecords
FROM Calendar
JOIN @T AS T
    ON Calendar.TheDate >= T.StartDate
    AND Calendar.TheDate <= T.EndDate
GROUP BY TheDate
```

Results:

```
TheDate     |   NumberOfRecords
2018-09-24  |   2
2018-09-25  |   2
2018-09-26  |   2
2018-09-27  |   2
2018-09-28  |   2
2018-09-29  |   2
2018-09-30  |   2
2018-10-01  |   1
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/VFMU34458)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try following SQL CTE query where I have used a [SQL dates table function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-dates-table-using-tsql-cte-calendar-table.aspx) [dbo].[DatesTable] which produces a list of dates between min date and max date in the source table

```
;with boundaries as (
    select
        min(StartDate) minD, max(EndDate) maxD
    from DateRanges
), dates as (
    select
        dates.[date]
    from boundaries
    cross apply [dbo].[DatesTable](minD, maxD) as dates
)
select dates.[date], count(*) as [count]
from dates
inner join DateRanges
on dates.date between DateRanges.StartDate and DateRanges.EndDate
group by dates.[date]
order by dates.[date]
```

The output is as expected

[image]

Comment: Using an existing Calendar table is probably the best way to get the desired results. However, please avoid using implicit joins - Explicit joins are a part of ANSI-SQL for over 25 years now.

Comment: Why cross apply with a where clause instead of a simple join?

Comment: I got it now :) Thanks for suggestion

Comment: In fact for readibility above code is better, but when I execute and check execution plans they seem to be executed in the same way

Comment: Yes, the query optimizer is smart enough to treat the cross apply/join with a where clause as an inner join. However, as you wrote yourself - a simple inner join is more readable.